# Resharper not recognizing Managed C++ /clr project referenced within a C# project

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I have had this problem for a long time.  I have a .net solution that contains both C# and Managed C++ projects.  The StartUp project is a C# project which reference the Managed C++ project.   **Everything compiles and executes fine**.  However, Resharper flags the namespace and Classes defined in my Managed C++ project as unresolved:

[image: Resharper Error]

How Can I tell Resharper to "Get the Memo" that my Managed C++ namespace and Classes are valid?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231731/why-cant-i-reference-my-class-library Maybe it'll help

Comment: @Brandon Tried clean, rebuild all and closing all the open source tabs, didn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe you should send the Memo to Resharper?

Comment: Please post this issue on http://youtrack.jetbrains.net, attaching the source code if possible. Thanks.

Comment: 3 years later, this problem still seems unresolved. I have a solution where this worked nicely for a long time, but now it doesn't any more, not sure why. When I try to clear the Reshaper caches, it finds the references, but that gets broken again on the next compilation of the project. 
Any insights on how to solve this in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I then realized that since the C++/clr project is an infrastructure project I rarely touch any more, I can simply unload it in the project after making sure it is properly built in all needed configurations.

After unloading the project, and a solution rebuild for extra safety, it seems ReSharper didn't "know" about the referenced project, and only used its built assembly, and the problem didn't occur anymore.