# NancyFX and adding another project as reference doesn't work

Tags: nancy

I created a nancyfx iis host solution from the nancyfx templates.  I was wanting to put my domain in a separate project but found that adding that project to the nancyfx project resulted in a the yellow exclamation point beside of the reference and at compile time I was getting errors about the reference to the namespace.

I likely have overlooked something very simple but I can't figure out why this is happening.  (I may be able to compile the domain project and add the dll reference but I prefer to just reference the project.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a Nancy issue - are you sure both projects are targeting the same version of the .net framework?

Comment: Yeah I agree that it doesn't sound like a nancy issue and I did check that they were both referencing the same version of the .net framework.  I also found this describing some strange behavior with VS & Resharper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231731/why-cant-i-reference-my-class-library.  It seems old but worth a try I guess.  (I can't try anything until this evening but I will check the version again and will try to close and reopen things)

Comment: Wow i decided to take a quick look instead of waiting 8 hours and the nancy template defaults to 4 and new class libraries default to 4.5.  Dumb moment for the day (One of many I'm sure).  I know I looked for that and also looked for the same CPU target last night must have seen the 4 and my mind filled in the .5.  Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: That's exactly what my problem was.  Thanks for the answer.